# VS 2010: project is out of date

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

> This project is out of date. Would you like to rebuild it?

Такая ошибка вылазит при старте дебага.

При этом неважно, какой код написан и как давно. Даже рабочие проекты, созданные на других машинах при запуске выдают эту ошибку.

Первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой. VS установлена корректно. Полагаю дело в каких-то настройках?

Comment: А компилируется ли ваш код вообще?

Comment: Конечно. На другой машине, на такой-же VS.

Comment: А на этой компилируется? Мало ли, может на другой машине другие настройки проекта.

Comment: Выскакивает ошибка, что проект старый, как только жму дебаг.

Comment: Окей, подойдём с другой стороны. Нажмите Ctrl + Shift + B и загляните в окошко Output. Что там?

Comment: "Hi.exe": "C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll" geladen, Cannot find or open the PDB file
"Hi.exe": "C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll" geladen, Cannot find or open the PDB file
"Hi.exe": "C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll" geladen, Cannot find or open the PDB file
"Hi.exe": "C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll" geladen, Cannot find or open the PDB file
"Hi.exe": "C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll" geladen, Cannot find or open the PDB file
"Hi.exe": "C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll" geladen, Cannot find or open the PDB file
И много ещё других файлов, которые он не может найти, но почему?

Comment: Насчёт PDB игнорируйте, это нормально. Положите лучше весь лог на pastebin.com.

Comment: Ещё есть "Hi.exe": "C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.6001.18000_none_886786f450a74a05\comctl32.dll" geladen, Cannot find or open the PDB file

Comment: И в конце
Der Thread 'Win32-Thread' (0xf18) hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Das Programm "[3140] VS_0.exe: Systemeigen" wurde mit Code 0 (0x0) beendet.
Все остальные ошибки, как в предидущем коменте.

Comment: Тогда никаких ошибок нету, программа нормально отработала до конца и завершилась.

Answer (score 1):

Это так и должно быть. Если код изменён, то оно появляется. Нажимешь Yes - всё компилируется и запускается. Нажимаешь No - ничего не компилируется и запускается тот exe'шник, который имеется. Для отключения в нём самом есть флажок Больше не спрашивать. А вот чтобы включить, придётся порытся в настройках. Советую не отключать.

Answer (score 0):

Студия вам просто говорит, что локальные исполняемые файлы не не соответствуют имеющемуся коду. Просто запустите компиляцию.